# Problema com select e utilização de ajax no Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estou tentando implementar um select com ajax no laravel 5 tenho a seguinte situação.

uma model class de estado

```
class Estados extends Model {

protected $table = 'estados';


public function cidades() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\Painel\Cidades', 'id_estado', 'id');
 }
}
```

uma model class de cidades

```
class Cidades extends Model {
protected $table = 'cidades';

public function pessoaFisica() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Painel\PessoaFisica');
}

public function estado() {
    return $this->belongsTo ( 'App\Models\Painel\Estados', 'id_estados' );
}
}
```

daí fiz o seguinte em minha view fiz o seguinte dois selects e um método js.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Estado
                    <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control input-sm">
                        <option value="">Escolha o Estado</option>
                        @foreach($estados as $estado)
                            <option value="{{$estado->id}}">{{ $estado->uf }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                       </select>
                </label>
            </div>



            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Cidade
                    <select id="cidade" class="form-control input-sm" name="cidade">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                    </label>
                    </div>

            </div>
```

segue o js

```
 <script>
     $('#estado').on('change', function(e){
         console.log(e);
         var estado = e.target.value;

         $.get('/estados?estado' + estado, function(data) {

             $('#cidade').empty();
             $.each(data, function(index,subcatObj){
                 $('#cidade').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+ subcatObj.nome </option>);
             });
         });
     });
 </script>
```

para povoar meu select de estado em meu controller fiz o seguinte.

```
public function getAdicionar() {

    $estados = Estados::all();

    return view("painel.admin.adicionarpessoafisica", compact("estados"));

}
```

e por fim mas não menos importante fiz o seguinte em minha rota.

```
Route::get('/estados',function() {
    $estado = Input::get('estado');

    $cidades = Cidades::where('id_estado', '=', $estado)->get();

    return Response::json($cidades);

});
```

O problema que está acontecendo é o seguinte ao tentar carregar o segundo select que depende do primeiro não está acontecendo nada.

Comment: Qual o problema? É no Javascript, não tá dando pra entender.

Comment: é verdade esqueci de falar o que está acontecendo, não está carregando o segundo select... creio que sim é o no js

Comment: editei a pergunta @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: O que o console do navegador mostra? Tem algum erro de sintaxe ou falha de carregamento na aba Rede?

Comment: Não tem nenhuma saida

Comment: Vc respondeu sua var estado para ver se ela não está vazia?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Você fez isto:

```
   $.get('/estados?estado' + estado, function(data) {
```

Mas o correto é isto:

```
   $.get('/estados?estado=' + estado, function(data) {
```

Faltou um sinal de `=`